# MVC 5 manually swapping identity user

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I've swapped my identity user:

```
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(newId, null);
```

This works for my needs but how am I suppose to reflect this change on my razor view where I use:

```
 @User.Identity.Name
```

Do I need to make any change on a Thread to persist this change for the current life cycle of the app?

Comment: I tried what you describe and it works *just fine*. In Controller Action method: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("John Doe"), null);` + in corresponding View: `@User.Identity.Name` -> shows **John Doe**.

Comment: So i guess my problem is that that change is happening after the view being already rendered.

Comment: You need to show more details, like *where* or *at which moment during a request* you set the User. A Controller Action **always** (by definition) runs before the View is rendered; and without an Action, there is no View to be rendered.